# What does the "+0" mean in the regexp \k<name+0>?

Tags: ruby, regex, backreference, named-captures

I'm new to Regular Expressions in Ruby, and I can't seem to find any solid documentation on what `\k<name+0>` means. It's the `+0` part that I'm not getting.

Here's an example - this Regexp matches palindromes:

```
\A(?<p>(?:(?<l>\w)\g<p>\k<l+0>|\w))\z
```

When I remove the `+0` in `\k<l+0>` it no longer matches correctly.
My tests:

```
>> /\A(?<p>(?:(?<l>\w)\g<p>\k<l+0>|\w))\z/.match "aabbcdcbbaa" 
#=> #<MatchData "aabbcdcbbaa" p:"aabbcdcbbaa" l:"c">

>> /\A(?<p>(?:(?<l>\w)\g<p>\k<l>|\w))\z/.match "aabbcdcbbaa" 
#=> nil
```

All I've done is remove the `+0`. I haven't yet found any documentation or example of this, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Great question. It's introduced me to the wonderful world of `\g<...>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `\k<l+0>` works together with the `(?<l>\w)`

The match of `(?<l>\w)` is stored in the capturing group named `'l'`

`\k<l+0>` Matches the same text that was matched by the named capturing group `'l'` when it was at the same recursion level as this backreference is now

Comment: Awesome! Also, it's `+0`. Are there any other functions like `+1` or anything?

Comment: @Cᴀʟʟᴏᴅᴀᴄɪᴛʏ +0 is the same recursion level, +1 is one level deeper,  -1 is one level less deep

Comment: I don't doubt what you say, but I'd like to find a reference for `+0`, preferably in the Ruby docs, but in the Oniguruma docs otherwise.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I found some documentation for this [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrecurse.html) if you're still interested.

Comment: Callodacity, thanks. Yes, that's what I was looking for. I should have checked that site as I use it for other reference purposes.